# older android version not recognizing SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt

Tags: android, ssl, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

The domain for an ingress running on my AWS EKS cluster is certified via cert-manager and Let's Encrypt.

The domain is considered secured in my desktop browser and my newer android phone.

In the browser of my older android phone, from nearly 10 years ago, the domain is considered insecure.

My question is, I am testing an android APP that makes API request to the above domain. In the newer android phone, the app works fine. but in the older android phone, the app is unable to login because I suspect that the API request to this domain is blocked, somehow.

Is that the case?

Comment: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/production-chain-changes/150739